# Add List of Algorithms in thesis's Table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms, algpseudocode

I am using template provided by our university for my thesis [link](https://www.cs.umanitoba.ca/perch/resources/1343664395thesistemplate-1.zip). I have started using latex recently. I tried different solutions from google for adding list of Algorithm, but none worked for me.

I am using following packages in my thesis for Algorithms.

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
```

What will be the best way to add list of algorithms in table of content with this template?

Comment: Do those packages create a a float type (with captions) for algorithms?  If so, just use \listof{...}.  If not, create your own float type using the float package.  Note, a list of algorithms is actually a list of captions.

Answer (score 2):

```
 \listofalgorithms
```

Simply worked for me, Added this to `frontmatter.tex` file. But formatting is different from rest of TOC. I will accept, if anyone else want to create an answer.